# How can I enable NX on my HP notebook?

Tags: windows-8, bios, nx, pae

I have an HP G62 Notebook PC running win7 64 bit. I want to install win8, but the "Windows 8 Upgrade Assistant" says secure boot isn't supported.

I ran core info which shows NX, PAE and SSE2 are all supported.

Does this mean that the BIOS disables these features and is this "assistant" 100% accurate?

If yes, and the main question, can someone link me to the simplest guide or tool to enable these even if it means getting a custom BIOS?

PS: I read other similar questions, but not one answered how to actually enable these. The laptop is only two years old. I paid a hefty sum to get a new processor/laptop time-proof for a while, but HP decided to update drivers only for last year's models! If my machine can support a new operating system, why do they want to force me to buy a new one?

Comment: Secure boot is an optional UEFI feature. It requires EFI, not BIOS. And it is optional for windows 8.

Answer (score 0):

Ignore the **secure boot** message and be happy that you're not having this function.

The NX issue can be caused when you disabled it with BCDEdit.